# How to set Section Border In tableview With Expanding and Collapsing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I'm Creating an design. In this Design I have to set Border colour for Section with collapsing and Expanding. I created a Xib file for Custom section but it's only show border colour in section . I want the Colour for whole section. No matter how many rows are inside.
and My first section Only expanding... If click on other it is not exapnding. Section o is expand.

```
struct Section {
var name: String!
var items: [String]!
var collapsed: Bool!

init(name: String, items: [String]) {
self.name = name
self.items = items
self.collapsed = true
}
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
   section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.preparingTableView {
        return 2
    } else {
        return (sections[section].collapsed!) ? 0 : 4
    }

}
```

This is the function for checking toggle button

```
@objc func toggleCollapse(sender: UIButton) {
  let section = sender.tag
  let collapsed = sections[section].collapsed
   
    sections[section].collapsed = !collapsed!

  // Reload section
    self.wareHouseTable.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) 
    as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
   }
```

this is what i want.
[image]

This is My xib File
[image]

Comment: can you share your section and cell xib UI interface builder in collapse and expand state.

Comment: Yes... I have updated My Quation.

Comment: I suggest you not use tableview. You can use uistackview and handle it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use section and cell such as bellow pic:

in header section there are 3 line(or view with gray color) or a view with border(right,left,top)
and cell there are 2 view in right,left equal constraint with section

you must remove separator and add a line above cell such as pic:

finally also you must check the last cell, and show bottom cell

[image]